# Only the last frame is displayed for imshow

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to apply background subtraction to my video using foreground detecto r.The background subtraction works.But imshow displays it only for the final frame . Any help would be appreciated

```
foregroundDetector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...'NumTrainingFrames', 100);

videoReader = vision.VideoFileReader('test1.mp4');

for i = 1:120
    frame = step(videoReader); % read the next video frame
%     imshow(frame);
    disp(i);
 foreground = step(foregroundDetector, frame);
    imshow(foreground);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent unnecessary graphics processing, if you continuously update a graphics object within a loop, the graphics aren't actually rendered until there is a pause in execution of an explicit `drawnow` is used to force the event queue to be flushed.

```
for k = 1:120
    frame = step(videoReader); % read the next video frame
    foreground = step(foregroundDetector, frame);
    imshow(foreground);

    % Explicitly force the renderer to update the display
    drawnow
end
```

As a side note, for better performance you should update your existing image object rather than constantly creating new ones with `imshow`.

```
frame = step(videoReader);
foreground = step(foregroundDetector, frame);
him = imshow(foreground);

for k = 1:119
    set(him, 'CData', foreground)
    drawnow

    frame = step(videoReader); % read the next video frame
    foreground = step(foregroundDetector, frame);
end
```